# Performance Issue in Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient

Tags: c#, uwp, win-universal-app

I have been using the [Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.web.http.httpclient) for my API Requests. My HttpClient is a singleton. I analyzed the resource timing for my API calls with the Network Profiler in Visual Studio. In the Timings split-up, I see that the Waiting (TTFB) part takes the most time (about 275ms. Sometimes it goes as high as 800ms).

[image]

As per this [doc](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network-performance/understanding-resource-timing), waiting time is the

> Time spent waiting for the initial response, also known as the Time To
>   First Byte. This time captures the latency of a round trip to the
>   server in addition to the time spent waiting for the server to deliver
>   the response.

When trying the same API call in different platforms mac(NSUrlSession) or android, the waiting time is significantly lower in same network. **My question is whether this waiting time delay is dependant on the HttpClient implementation? If not is there anything which needs to be changed in my NetworkAdapter code?**

Comment: do you same behaviour in consecutive requests ? you could try new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler
        {
            UseProxy = false
        });

and debug and see headers of requests (defaults) on android and wcf. i dont think httpclient implementation should be that slow.

Comment: i have analyzed the request info across platforms. they're the same including headers

Comment: oh okay. turning of Proxy or checking whether they are using http1.1 or http2 would be other options. I guess NSUrlSession would use http2 default and that could make  things faster especially for https. not sure which .NET version you are on and its httpclient supports http2 or not.

Comment: I have all this checked and its the same for all. proxy is disabled. Both uses HTTP/1.1

Answer (score -1):

The TTFB is a function of the round-trip time (RTT) and the server’s response time (SRT), both of which are mostly outside of the client OS’ control. Just as a basic sanity check, I would recommend measuring the TTFB using Scenario 1 of the [HttpClient SDK Sample app](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/HttpClient). One possible explanation would be that the Windows device doesn’t have the same network setup as the Mac/Android devices (e.g., are they all connected via WiFi? If so, are they all using the same band (2.4 GHz or 5 GHz)?). However, the most likely explanation is that the HTTP request being sent out by HttpClient differs from the one sent out by NSUrlSession (e.g., in terms of the headers), resulting in a different server-side processing time.

The TTFB is very site-dependent. Here's what I’m seeing on my end using the VS2017 Network Profiler with the HttpClient SDK sample app:

Bing.com:

[image: www.bing.com]

Amazon.com:

[image: www.amazon.com]

Microsoft.com:

[image: www.microsoft.com]

Comment: i tried my sample project as a wpf app. there a request takes 550 ms on average and in Uwp app response time is 300 ms on average. Shouldn't it be the same for both Wpf and uwp as the environment is the same?

Comment: Is the WPF app using System.Net.Http.HttpClient or is it using Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient?

Comment: Also, is the UWP vs WPF discrepancy in terms of TTFB?

Comment: the total time for the response. Is there a network profiler for Wpf?

Comment: System.Net.HttpClient in both cases. Isn't Windows.Web.HttpClient exclusive to UWP?

Comment: WinRT APIs including Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient can be used by a WPF app (see this blog post: https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2017/01/25/calling-windows-10-apis-desktop-application/).

Comment: Unfortunately,  I don't have any experience profiling WPF apps. What I do know is that System.Net.HttpClient uses a managed stack when running inside a WPF, but uses a native stack (written on top of Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient) when running inside a UWP app. That would explain the difference that you're seeing in terms of response times.

Comment: The System.Net.HttpClient implementation that's used in UWP apps is part of the .Net Core repo, which is open source: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/e0ba7aa8026280ee3571179cc06431baf1dfaaac/src/System.Net.Http/src/uap/System/Net/HttpClientHandler.cs . Notice the use of Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient ;)

Comment: Thanks. I have verified the headers and they are same for both mac and my windows. Other factors like connected to the same network via ethernet also same.

Comment: How are you measuring TTFB on mac/android?

Comment: I am measuring the total response time when comparing with mac.

Comment: What NSUrlSession callback are you listening for? I'm wondering whether it's the equivalent of HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Web.Http.HttpCompletionOption